# How to add link into html

Tags: html, wordpress

I want to add a link into the following code to make it run as a button that opens the link in the same window.

where do i add it in and how can you make it open in same window?

```
<div style="width: 200px; background-color: #bf8f42; opacity: 0.8; margin: auto; margin-top: 50px; padding: 10px;">View Flash Perks
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use anchor tag

```
<a href="http://where_to_go.com">
    <div style="width: 200px; background-color: #bf8f42; opacity: 0.8; margin: auto; margin-top: 50px; padding: 10px;">
    View Flash Perks
    </div>
</a>
```

Comment: thank you, it worked! However the text is red how can i change to white?

Comment: add color=white in div style. and please upvote and mark correct

Comment: how can I make the button darken when mouse hovers on top

Answer (score 0):

`<div style="width: 200px; background-color: #bf8f42; opacity: 0.8; margin: auto; margin-top: 50px; padding: 10px;"><a href="link"> View Flash Perks</a></div>`

It will open the link in same window.

Comment: thank you, however that made just the text a link but the code above worked

Answer (score 0):

Why is the text moved down?

[Example of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FOuHu.png)

Here is the code:

```
<p><a href="........"></p>
<div style="width: 200px; background-color: #bf8f42; opacity: 0.8; margin: 
auto; margin-top: 0px; padding: 10px;"><font color="white"><br />
View Flash Perks
</div>
<p></a>    </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want the whole div to work as a link use

```
<div style="width: 200px; background-color: #bf8f42; opacity: 0.8; margin: auto; margin-top: 50px; padding: 10px;" onclick="location.href='(link to page goes here)'">View Flash Perks
```